# MVC3 Razor HTML.DropDownList calculated field

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, razor

I want to calculate two value from two dropdownlist in MVC3 .Like I have MonthlyFee dropdownlist and ExamFee dropdownlist.I had taken data from another field with ViewBag and take data into  these dropdownlist.I want to add the values of this two drop downlist like Monthlyfee + ExamFee.Here is my razor code .So please provide me how can i add the two vales from a dropdownlist.

`<td>@Html.DropDownList("MonthlyFeeId", String.Empty)`
`@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MonthlyFee)</td>`

`<td>@Html.DropDownList("ExamFeeId", String.Empty)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ExamFee)</td>`

I have tried to calculate with jquery.But it calculate it's id , not it's value

Comment: Show us your jQuery code.  Be sure you access the value properly like `$('#MonthlyFeeId').val()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var total = parseInt($('#MonthlyFeeId').val()) + parseInt($('#ExamFeeId').val())
});
```

`total` will have the sum of your two dropdown values.